# Python: Fill empty rows of Dataframe with unique column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unique, fillna

Got Dataframe *df*

```
State   Item        Space   Date
AAA     Grape       0.125   2022-02-11
        Beans       0.0
AAA     Mango       0.25    2022-02-11
AAA     Beetroot    0.375   2022-02-11
        Carrot      0.5
```

Need to fill empty values in rows with that column's unique value.
Tried `df['State'].fillna(df['State'].unique(), inplace=True)` , didn't worked out.

**Expected Output:**

```
State   Item        Space   Date
AAA     Grape       0.125   2022-02-11
AAA     Beans       0.0     2022-02-11
AAA     Mango       0.25    2022-02-11
AAA     Beetroot    0.375   2022-02-11
AAA     Carrot      0.5     2022-02-11
```

Comment: You need constant values in first and last columns? Or there are some groups?

Answer (score 1):

If want replace each column by first non missing values first replace empty strings to missing values and then forward and backfill missing values:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)

df = df.ffill().bfill()
```